# CPP issue using variadic parameters (Args...) to log

Tags: c++, logging, variadic-functions

I'm trying to log some things on my cpp app.
I chose to go on variadic parameters.

My log functions :

```
inline void log() {}

template<class... Args>
inline void log(std::string_view first, const Args&... args)
{
    std::cout << first << std::endl;
    log(args...);
}
```

To test, I'm trying to log this message :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    log("I am a message to log ... ", "123456789" + i);
}
```

I'm having this unexpected result (it should be the same number for each log message, no ?) :

```
I am a message to log ...
123456789
I am a message to log ...
23456789
I am a message to log ...
3456789
I am a message to log ...
456789
I am a message to log ...
56789
I am a message to log ...
6789
I am a message to log ...
789
I am a message to log ...
89
I am a message to log ...
9
I am a message to log ...
```

I think I'm missing something, somewhere in my code...
I tried to run this code on 2 os (windows & linux mint), just to be sure x) !

Well, I'm stuck on this subject ...

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: It works very well, does exactly what you assigned, "123456789" + 1 is "23456789", "123456789" + 2 is "3456789". You might want to repeat the pointer arithmetic. *I'm having this unexpected result* - and what have you expected, we cant guess and read your mind.

Comment: It is unclear why you believe `"123456789" + i` would be "the same", regardless of the value of `i`.  Why perform this addition if you think it would have no effect?

Comment: That carefully about what the type of `"123456789"` is, and arithmetic on that type does.

Comment: If you instead made the function `template <class First, class... Args> inline void log(First&& first, const Args&... args)` you could log like this: `log("I am a message to log ... ", "123456789", i);` [example](https://godbolt.org/z/rf8zYbP79)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in comments, your snippet behave as expected. See, problem is that you do `"123456789" + i`. `"123456789"` is `const char*`. So adding `i` is pointer arithmetic, where you in fact changing starting position of your data to print.

Also already answered, fix you looking for is remove addition and make i new parameter of log function.